# Sequence and formula

Tags: sequences-and-series

We have this sequence of numbers:

4,7,8,10,12,13,14,16,18,19,20,22,24,25,26,28,30....

We see the pattern that begins from "7"
{+1 +2+2+1}

Can we find a formula for all the numbers(including "4")?

Comment: Why do people ask about a (pattern in a) sequence without saying how it is produced? This way, it is not about mathematics at all. (Be prepared for downvotes.)

Comment: Excuse me, this is my second post in stack exchange.

Comment: I didn't know the rules.

Comment: $$a_n=\begin{cases}4&n=0\\\frac{11}2+\frac32n+\frac12\cos{\left(\frac{\pi n}2\right)}&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Comment: @Craftsman Welcome to the Math Stackexchange. If you need help, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/help). Please try to give context in your questions and show an attempt.

Comment: @metamorphy Excuse me but i clearly dont understand what you are saying...

Comment: @metamorphy You're perfect in a mathematical sense, "only respect data, don't guess". But IMHO the OP is asking about a sequence that *does obey* some pattern.

Comment: @metamorphy Right. I'll reword what I think is the OP's question: "Given the sequence (most?) produced by this pattern, which is the equivalent formula?"

Comment: The pattern i wrote  {+1 +2 +2 +1} continues infinetely as you see.The 5 numbers after 30 are 31  32  34  36  37 and going on.

Comment: Ok, seems I didn't see that it's a "definition". Sorry then.